# Optionals and Dictionaries in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I've been having an issue with a dictionary in Swift and it had to do with how I defined the property.  In Objective-C it's possible to define a dictionary property and then fill the dictionary later in code.  I tried to define a dictionary in Swift as an optional and ran into a number of errors.  Here is what I typed.

```
var URLDictionary : [String:String]?
```

I tried to set a string property by accessing a value from the dictionary with the key.

```
self.stringProperty = URLDictionary["Key"]
```

However, I received the following error message.

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String:String]' with an index of
>   type'String'

By removing the ? from the line

```
var URLDictionary : [String:String]?
```

to give

```
var URLDictionary : [String:String]
```

the error message goes away.

The reason I used the ? in the first place was because I received a warning when I originally declared the dictionary property and the question mark made it go away.  The warning was

> Stored property 'URLDictionary' without initial value prevents
>   synthesized initializers.

My question is, how do you or can you define a dictionary as an optional?  If I know the dictionary values from the beginning I am assuming it would make sense to fill the dictionary when it is declared.

Take care,

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to work on fixing your original error and the rest of your errors should fix themselves because you're not dealing with an optional dictionary.

Your original error was:

> Stored property 'URLDictionary' without initial value prevents synthesized initializers.

Xcode is complaining that you've created a dictionary but not given it an initial value. To give the `URLDictionary` an initial value you can do either of the following:

**1.** Give `URLDictionary` an default property value of an empty dictionary (or it could already contain keys and values if you want...)

```
class MyClass {
    var URLDictionary = [String: String]()
}
```

**2.** Use the `init` method to assign `URLDictionary` a value.

```
class MyClass {
    var URLDictionary: [String: String]

    init(urlDict: [String: String]) {
        self.URLDictionary = urlDict
    }
}
```

The second approach is better if you want to give `URLDictionary` a value whilst you're initialising it.

For more information I would recommend looking at [*The Swift Programming Language: Initialization*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

---

If for some reason you still want an optional dictionary lets have a look at the other error message:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String:String]' with an index of type'String'

Unfortunately, the message is a bit misleading and using a `String` as the key isn't really the cause of the problem. Instead I suspect `stringProperty` is a `String`; **not** an optional `String`.

If you look at the documentation you'll see the `subscript` method of a `Dictionary` returns an optional that indicates whether a value existed for the key supplied.

```
subscript(key: Key) -> Value?
```

Therefore, you're trying to assign an optional (returned by `URLDictionary`) to a non-optional (`stringProperty`). To solve this you could use optional binding and optional chaining, like so:

```
// Note '?' after URLDictionary to check if URLDictionary is non-nil.
if let value = myClassInstance.URLDictionary?["Key"] {
    stringProperty = value
}
```

Hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: Thank you.  Great answer.  Thanks for taking the time to clearly explain this.

Answer (score -1):

Do this `var URLDictionary : [String:String]!` I added `!` after `[String:String]`

This will tell the compiler that it will be defined and not throw the warning and you wont need to use Optional either

Comment: Except this *IS* using an optional.